# Conformal mapping for calculating magnetic reluctance

Tags: mathematical-physics, magnetic-fields

I work currently on the calculation of magnetic resistance for a air-gap of an electrical machine. For this I am using conformal transformations. I am doing this on a 2D slice. As the machine is obviously round I first use a logarithmic transformation to convert it to a polygonal shape. After that I use a Schwarz-Christoffel transformation to map the polygon to a rectangle.

For the said rectangle I assume a homogeneous field distribution. A fine mesh is set to represent the homogeneous field distribution. This mesh is maped back to the real(physical) geometry. What I get is a very nice representation of the field and equipotential lines. I approximate every of the small quadrilaterals as rectangles and calculate the resistance of them. So I get the resistance. For the Schwarz-Christoffel Transformation I use the [SC-Toolbox](http://www.math.udel.edu/~driscoll/SC/) by Tobin A. Driscoll

Here you can see a simple example of what I'm trying to calculate:
[image]
[Larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0fdi.png)

My question is if the there is a more elegant way to get the resistance directly from the transformed (canonical) space, meaning the rectangle. I asked this question already on the [math portal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754818/conformal-equivalence-of-resistance) in more general terms, but I wasn't able to get an adequate answer

I am currently in the phase of writing documentation for my project, so I wanted to see if there is some deeper physical/mathematical explanation for it.

Comment: The question was answered on the math portal. If you are interested in the answer go to this [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754818/conformal-equivalence-of-resistance).